# Moving minheap.top to maxheap.top where maxheap.top <= minheap.top

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a maxheap and a minheap where the maximum element of the maxheap is less than or equal to the minimum element of the minheap.

I now want to move the minimum element of the minheap to become the maximum element of the maxheap.

One way to do this would be to pop the top element of the minheap and push it onto the maxheap.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Here is what I ended up doing**:

I actually had to insert an element into minheap and then do the operation described above, I did the following:

```
// place value to insert at end of minheap
mintoph[mintoph_size] = R;

// use std::pop_heap, minimum element now at end
pop_heap(mintoph.begin(), mintoph.begin() + mintoph_size + 1, greater<int>());

// (*) make room in maxheap at top
for (int pos = maxboth_size++; pos > 0;)
{
    int parent = (pos - 1) / 2;
    maxboth[pos] = maxboth[parent];
    pos = parent;
}

// move element from back of minheap to maxheap head
maxboth[0] = mintoph[mintoph_size];
```

There is a waste of already paid-for comparisons at step `(*)` above, as parents are demoted to children, but I think this is unavoidable.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to "cross-optimise" based on the fact that you have two data structures; after all, they must both have their invariants maintained independently (unless, of course, you're prepared to move to a different data structure).  I think the only thing that might help you is the fact that the item you're going to insert is guaranteed to be the maximum.

Comment: Incidentally, your question title ("maxheap.top to minheap.top") doesn't match your question body ("move minimum element of minheap...").

Comment: actually i want to go in both directions, but it's a mirror image, so one way will provide the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really need is an efficient way to insert into a priority queue when you know that the element being inserted is smaller/bigger than the min/max, depending on whether this is a min-heap or a max-heap.  For the traditional "heap" data structure, this takes O(log n) time.

But if you are willing to use a different representation for your priority queues than the traditional "heap" data structure, then such an insert can trivially be made to run in O(1) time.  Many different kinds of priority queues can do this, such as leftist heaps, skew heaps, or pairing heaps.

Edit: Of course, you'll still need to pay the cost of removing from the original priority queue, which will likely be O(log n) anyway, although there are approaches that may help there as well, such as "lazy deletes".

Comment: Concretely, to insert a known-smallest element into a min-heap implemented as a leftist heap, create a new root node containing the inserted element, make the old root its left child, and leave its right child empty.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be best served by using a min-max-heap or treap.  min-max-heap seems tailor-made for what you're doing, but treaps are so dang well-rounded that they might work well too - especially if you need a little more than just looking up minimums and maximums and adding values.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap

Comment: This is not correct, if I required the minimum and maximum of the same set of values than a minmax heap would be appropriate.  The question is about two seperate sets where the minimum of one is >= maximum of the other.

Answer (score -1):

Use min-max heap, it's a double ended priority queue, you can do this thing in o(lgn), you can not do it in less than O(lgn)

but you can use amortized algorithms that they do insertion in o(1) like fibonacci heap,

Comment: You do understand that `maxheap.top <= minheap.top` and not `minheap.top <= maxheap.top` right?

Comment: you could insert your node as a leaf in the max heap, then call your heapify function

Comment: I think you do not understand my answer, read more about tree algorithms, refer to CLRS introduction to algorithms

Comment: You don't understand the problem.  The minheap and maxheap are holding separate sets of data, all elements of the minheap are greater than all the elements of the maxheap (and visa-versa).  A min-max heap is not applicable.  A min-max heap is for where you have a single set and want to know simultaneously the maximum and minimum element.